How to communicate like client-server between Pods in a private subnet in Kubernetes cluster?
I have 2 deployment, 2 respective node port services, both targeted to port 80 in my EKS cluster runs in AWS environment.
My Terraform templates are like as follows:
Resource: Kubernetes Ingress Class Manifest
# File: 01. ingress_class.tf

resource "kubernetes_ingress_class_v1" "ingress_class_default" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.loadbalancer_controller]
  metadata {
    name = "ingress-class"
    # annotations = {
    #   "ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "true"
    # }
  }  
  spec {
    controller = "ingress.k8s.aws/alb"
  }
}

Kubernetes API Deployment Manifest
# File: 02. api.tf

resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "api" {
  metadata {
    name = "api-deployment"
    labels = {
      app = "api"
    }
  } 
 
  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "api"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "api"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "my_image"
          name  = "api"
          env {
            name = "BASE_CLIENT_URL"
            value = "http://client"
          }
          port {
            container_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Kubernetes Client Deployment Manifest
# File: 03. client.tf

resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "client" {
  metadata {
    name = "client-deployment"
    labels = {
      app = "client"
    }
  } 
 
  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "client"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "client"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "my_image"
          name  = "client"
          
          env {
            name = "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL"
            value = "http://api"
          }
          env {
            name = "NEXTAUTH_SECRET"
            value = "SDKLFKasjdaeirpiwiKJKIOOIJDasdfd"
          }
          env {
            name = "NEXTAUTH_URL"
            value = "http://api/api/auth"
          }
          
          port {
            container_port = 80
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

Kubernetes Service Manifest API Nodeport
# Filename: 04. api-nodeport.tf

resource "kubernetes_service_v1" "api_np_service" {
  metadata {
    name = "api-nginx-nodeport-service"
    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path" = "/api"
    }    
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_deployment_v1.api.spec.0.selector.0.match_labels.app
    }
    port {
      name        = "http"
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }
    type = "NodePort"
  }
}

Kubernetes Service Manifest Client Nodeport
# Filename: 05. client-nodeport.tf

resource "kubernetes_service_v1" "client_np_service" {
  metadata {
    name = "client-nginx-nodeport-service"
    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path" = "/"
    }    
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_deployment_v1.client.spec.0.selector.0.match_labels.app
    }
    port {
      name        = "http"
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }
    type = "NodePort"
  }
}

Kubernetes Service Manifest Load Balancer
# Filename: 06. ingress-service.tf

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress-service"
    annotations = {
      # Load Balancer Name
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name" = "ingress-service"
      # Ingress Core Settings
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" = "internet-facing"
      # Health Check Settings
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol" =  "HTTP"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port" = "traffic-port"
      #Important Note:  Need to add health check path annotations in service level if we are planning to use multiple targets in a load balancer    
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds" = 15
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds" = 5
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes" = 200
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count" = 2
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count" = 2
    }    
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "ingress-class" # IngressClass
    default_backend {
      service {
        name = kubernetes_service_v1.client_np_service.metadata[0].name
        port {
          number = 80
        }
      }
    }

    rule {
      http {
        
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.api_np_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/api/v1/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

After successful deployment I can access them via browser:

Client: http://ingress-service-38383838.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
API: http://ingress-service-38383838.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v1

But my Client app failed to access the API service to fetch data.
I don't understand what I am missing?

Have you checked the logs of the failed request? Perhaps you could exec onto a pod of the first API using kubectl and try to make a cURL request to the other API and see what you get. My initial instinct is a networking rule issue - I would check the inbound and outbound rules on the NSG first. Otherwise if your application supports ClientIP instead of NodePort, you can specify an internal IP address on the services, share that IP as the URL, and send HTTP messages that never have to leave the subnet or cluster.

Where is the client running?  (Is it a browser-based application, or is it exclusively a server-side program running in its own Pod?)  What URL are you trying to connect to, with what client code, connecting to what server code?  What error do you get?
